# how to give the drop down sub menu a slide down effect with delay

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I want to give the on hover submenu which shows fast a slidedown effects in CSS3

this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/BSZwP/

CSS

```
#nav > li:hover > a, #nav > a:hover {
    color: #008f43;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
 }
```

But it's not working

Comment: What property are you trying to get a transition on? I only see you changing the display to block to display the sub menus, and display is not transitionable. (The increased padding for your sub-sub menus is working however.)

Comment: as the display block is too fast....i want them to slide down with css3 ease kind of animation...I tried a lot kinds stuck here

Comment: Then you have to use another property to switch them between hidden and shown – height would work f.e., but only if the target height is given as a numeric value as well, `auto` won’t work either.

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: On what? Could you please ask _specific_ questions, and make sure first that you know what properties transitions can be used on and what properties they can not be used on, and why?

Comment: when hovering on item the submenu just showsup very fast..i want them to fade in with a delay or slide down

Comment: I know what you _want_, you don’t have to repeat that over and over. And I already told you what you should get yourself informed about as well.